# Do I need to use SSL on a web page if the web service already uses it?

Tags: web-services, ssl, https

Would a web page need to use SSL in order to prevent eavesdropping if it makes all requests through the web service that already uses SSL?

I am leaning more towards yes it would need to use SSL on the web page side as well but I am not confident.

Can someone explain to me why the web page would need it or not?

Comment: Please provide more details: Do I understand you correctly that you have a web page which is calling web services? And the website is delivered via unencrypted http, but the webservices are accessed via ssl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing else, the parent page should be loaded through SSL as well to prevent any "mixed content" warning messages. Even if the service calls in the background are done via SSL, the main page won't show the usual SSL indicators, making users think it's totally unsecured.